# webpage display issue in IE10

Tags: html, servlets, internet-explorer-10, frames, frameset

```
    public void DisplayIndexPage(PrintWriter out, String htmlPath)
        {
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Test IE 10 </title>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE = JavaScript>
        function hintPopUp()
        {
        if (navigator.appName == "Netscape")
        {   
        alert("Please install Internet Explorer");
        }
        }
        </SCRIPT>
        </head>
        <frameset cols="192,*" border=0 frameborder=0>
        <frame name="menu" src="some java file 1" noresize >
        <frameset rows="55,50,*" border=0 frameborder=0>
        <frame name="banner" scrolling="no" noresize src="/IE10/header.html"> 
        <frame name="bottom" scrolling="no" noresize src="JAVA file 2"> 
        <frame name="main" src="/IE10/main.html"> 
        </frameset>
        <noframes>
        <body onLoad="hintPopUp();"> 
        <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>
        </body>
        </noframes>
        </frameset>
        </html>
}
```

I have written the above code in servlet(using out.println)  user defined method then calling this method inside the doPost method. when access this page in IE10 the source code is printed in the browser.The webpage is working fine in previous IE versions.

Answer (score 0):

The frames/frameset is your issue for IE10. For some reason it doesn't support it but here is a link for the fix: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx